# How to get total memory/RAM in GO?

Tags: go

How can I get the total amount of memory/RAM attached to a system in Go? I want to use native code only if possible. I have found a library that wraps linux sysinfo command. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: If you're after a Linux specific way, just read and parse `/proc/meminfo`. For a cross platform solution, you'll need to do OS specific calls.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Besides [runtime.MemStats](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#ReadMemStats) you can use [gosigar](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gosigar) to monitor system memory.

Comment: `runtime.MemStats` doesn't give system memory, only various kinds of memory in use by the current process.

Answer (score 18):

cgo & linux solution

```
package main

// #include <unistd.h>
import "C"

func main() {
    println(C.sysconf(C._SC_PHYS_PAGES)*C.sysconf(C._SC_PAGE_SIZE), " bytes")
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this seems to be the best option currently :(

Comment: if I remember correctly, c in go is very slow. Am I right?

Comment: @kabanek the system memory doesn't change often presumably, call it once and cache it

Comment: Exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 5):

You can read */proc/meminfo* file directly in your Go program, as @Intermerne suggests.
For example, you have the next structure:

```golang
type Memory struct {
    MemTotal     int
    MemFree      int
    MemAvailable int
}
```

You can just fill structure from the */proc/meminfo*:

```golang
func ReadMemoryStats() Memory {
    file, err := os.Open("/proc/meminfo")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    res := Memory{}
    for scanner.Scan() {
        key, value := parseLine(scanner.Text())
        switch key {
        case "MemTotal":
            res.MemTotal = value
        case "MemFree":
            res.MemFree = value
        case "MemAvailable":
            res.MemAvailable = value
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

Here is a code of parsing separate line (but I think it could be done more efficiently):

```golang
func parseLine(raw string) (key string, value int) {
    fmt.Println(raw)
    text := strings.ReplaceAll(raw[:len(raw)-2], " ", "")
    keyValue := strings.Split(text, ":")
    return keyValue[0], toInt(keyValue[1])
}

func toInt(raw string) int {
    if raw == "" {
        return 0
    }
    res, err := strconv.Atoi(raw)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return res
}
```

More about "/proc/meminfo" you can read from the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/proc.html#meminfo)

Answer (score 2):

In my research on this I came across the [memory package](https://github.com/pbnjay/memory) that implements this for a number of different platforms. If you're looking for a quick and easy solution without CGO, this might be your best option.

From the README:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/pbnjay/memory"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Total system memory: %d\n", memory.TotalMemory())
}
```

On [go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mDud5Vwnue_8):

```
Total system memory: 104857600
```